# Flagging automatically flagged posts as invalid

Tags: discussion, support, moderation, flagging, 10k-tools

This is perhaps more of a personal question regarding moderation, but others might also have come across it. Hence its presence here.

The question [Switch to LyX Code Keyboard Shortcut](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/60043/5764) had a simple answer, actually answered by the OP. It's simplicity led to it being flagged *automatically* as having a "low answer quality score" and subsequently showed up in the [10K-tools](https://tex.stackexchange.com/tools/) review. Since I followed the original commentary of the question and its subsequent answer, I flagged it as being an "invalid flag"; perhaps considering it my 2-cents worth of contributing:

[image]

However, as seen above, this was "disputed" by a moderator. What should one do in such cases? For example, I thought this was a valid use of an "invalid flag" flag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You've acted entirely correctly: the whole point of the 10k tools is to spread the load of keeping on top of issues beyond a small group of mods to everyone who has 'invested' heavily in the site. On the particular question you point to, I'm not quite sure what the 'disputed' is supposed to mean. Like you, I felt the answer was fine, with the shortness 'confusing' the automated tools. I dismissed the flag: presumably the *flag itself* is therefore disputed, rather than your suggesting 'invalid'.

Comment: From a site user's perspective, it seems like there are two *visible* flags: helpful, or disputed (not counting ignored flags that float away into the abyss). And those two could be considered polar opposites: the former being a pat on the back; the latter being a kick in the backside. :) Note that helpful flags are badge-appropriate, and one might be inclined to only flag where it will be helpful...

Comment: Could any “disagree” flag be automatically “disputed” (by the user who raised the original flag)? Doesn't really make sense for flags raised by system itself, but maybe SE treats these flags the same way as user-raised flags for simplicity.

Comment: As is [answered](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/224755/168244) in [“It has invalid flags” flag - when resolving, mark as opposite to other flags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/224749/168244), one could consider "helpful" flags as carrying a weight of +1, "disputed" a weight of 0 and "rejected" a weight of -1 (I guess in-line with [the original flag weight system](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84859/168244)). Admittedly, "disputed" has a more negative connotation than being considered "neutral."