# Disputed "invalid flag" 2nd edition

Tags: support, bug, flagging

This is a sort-of follow-up to: [Flagging automatically flagged posts as invalid](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2555/flagging-automatically-flagged-posts-as-invalid)

The difference is that in this case, it is not an automatic flag.

I marked as "invalid" the flags on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99376/11002). However, the flag history says:

> disputed - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

[image]

The explanatory text shows that moderator agreed with me that flags on that post are invalid, yet my flag is "disputed". Since I don't have many flags, I was able to find all my disputed flags, and this is really one of them (it really counts as "disputed" like that my action was wrong).

I'm not after any statistics about flags, I just want to find the reasons for this, and to see whether my actions were correct. And if they were, I believe it is a bug in the system.

**Remark:** I have couple flags of this type (marking other flag as "invalid") that are "helpful". This means that it is not a *general case of all "invalid" flags*, but rather some (randomly) appearing effect.

Comment: Seems to be "by design": http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161645/why-do-invalid-flag-flags-get-disputed

Comment: @lockstep From there it seems more as "without any conclusion" :-/

Comment: From what I've picked up in the mod chat, this is 'by design': it does not matter who disagrees, any 'dispute' is shown up for everyone involved (except mods taking action).

Comment: @JosephWright Thanks. IMHO it does not make sense, but whatever. The only thing I don't like in the end is that it corrupts the feedback for myself of my "flagging correctness ratio".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since this [seems to be by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/161645/why-do-invalid-flag-flags-get-disputed), I posted a feature request for separation of "invalid flag" flags from all the other ones in the statistics:

[Separate "invalid flags" in the flag statistics](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/169409/separate-invalid-flags-in-the-flag-statistics)